# How to find recent sql update operations acting upon a certain table (SQL Server 2005)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

say I want to find the latest added rows (UPDATE by any user, not necessarily the one which is executing UPDATE)  in XX table.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use a Transaction Log reader tool. There are several free ones available as well as commercial offerings.

- [ApexSQL Log](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.asp)

You could also try [this](http://www.mssqlcity.com/Articles/KnowHow/ViewLog.htm) undocumented command:

```
 DBCC LOG(<database name>[,{0|1|2|3|4}]).
```

If you're using SQL Server 2000, RedGate have a free tool called [SQL Log Rescue](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Log_Rescue/index.htm).

EDIT:  Documentation for DBC LOG: 
[(1)](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.39996_1250/html/svrtsg/svrtsg102.htm) [(2)](http://www.mssqlcity.com/Articles/Undoc/SQL2000UndocDBCC.htm#part_2_8)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to SQL Docs & look for OUTPUT clause (that you can use with UPDATE/INSERT to get the affected records).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx) will allow you to track hits to the database in real time.  You can set filters on a number of properties to ge the output you need.