# How to tell last update/insert activity on a table sql 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, metadata

I am trying to find out when the last insert/update was done to a specific table in our sql 2005 db. The data does not have a timestamp, so I can not tell that way. Are there any dmv out there that would assist me in this?

Thanks,
hp

**Duplicate**: [How to find recent sql update operations acting upon a certain table (SQL Server 2005)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301060/how-to-find-recent-sql-update-operations-acting-upon-a-certain-table-sql-server)

Comment: I don't find this question to be a duplicate, as this one wants the date of the last modification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a link that could help you out:

[Last Update Time](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/09/sql-server-find-last-date-time-updated-for-any-table/) from blog.sqlauthority.com

A part of that post contains this code: where 'AdventureWorks' is the Catalog name and 'test' is the table name

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS DatabaseName, last_user_update,*
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
WHERE database_id = DB_ID( 'AdventureWorks')
AND OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID('test')
```

Comment: The one gotcha with this is that the user has to have the permission "VIEW SERVER STATE" or it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS DatabaseName, last_user_update,*
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
WHERE database_id = DB_ID( 'AdventureWorks')
AND OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID('test')
```

Works fine, but if you look at the source table: sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats you'll realise that table have to be indexed in order for them to show up in here. You maybe thinking surely all tables are indexed, we take snapshots for data warehousing and there is no need to index these tables however we do like to show people when they were last updated.

Whilst it appears if you create a table in SQL with no index and update it/add data this sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats gets updated. We update our tables with SSIS and there are no entries for our tables in sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats.